# Energy dissipation

Tags: functional-analysis, heat-equation

I've been asked to prove the following, but I don't find the way..

Let $\Omega\subset\left\{0<x_n<a\right\}$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that it is bounded in the $n^{th}$ coordinate. Prove that the solution of the heat equation 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{lc}
u_t=\Delta u && in\ \Omega \\
u=0 && on\ \partial\Omega \\
u(x,0)=u_0(x) && in\ \Omega
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
satisfies
\begin{equation*}
\int_\Omega \dfrac{1}{2}u^2\leq M\cdot e^{-\delta t},
\end{equation*}
for some $M,\delta>0$.

By showing this it is easily seen that any solution of this problem tends to $0$ as $t$ tends to $\infty$.

The problem that follows from this one is the next one:

Can one prove, with similar methods, that all the solutions of the problem
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{lc}
u_t=\Delta u && in\ \Omega \\
\nabla u\cdot n=0 && on\ \partial\Omega \\
u(x,0)=u_0(x) && in\ \Omega
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
where $n$ is the exterior normal vector of $\partial\Omega$, tend to steady solutions? Given an initial condition $u_0$, can one predict which is the value of the constant solution at which $u(x,t)$ tends as $t$ tends to $\infty$?

I'd be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The operator $\Delta$ should be selfadjoint on the spatial domain with the desired boundary conditions. That allows you to write the solution as $u=e^{t\Delta}u_{0}$. The spectrum of $\Delta$ is normally going to be non-positive. So all of the modes will decay in time unless you have a non-trivial mode with eigenvalue $0$--that one can be present at $t=\infty$. In the first problem, that doesn't happen, and all of the modes die out.

In the second problem, the constant functions are eigenfunctions of the Laplacian operator because the domain consists of functions with the normal derivative equal to $0$. So the constant mode can persist without being damped in time. It fact, you know what the ultimate constant value will be: it will be the projection onto the eigenfunction which is the constant function. That projection is
$$
                     \frac{(u_{0},1)}{(1,1)}1,
$$
assuming the spatial region is finite. If the spatial region is finite, then the above is nothing more than the average of the initial date $u_{0}$ over the whole region, which is probably what you would expect for a heat solution inside an insulated body, which is what normal derivative $0$ means. Such a mode is unchanged throughout time.

Comment: "The spectrum of $\Delta$ is normally going to be non-positive." --I was under the impression that it was always non-positive; how can you construct an eigenfunction with positive eigenvalue?

Comment: @NickThompson : There are weird things that happen even in $1-d$, but they require unusual endpoint conditions. For example, if you consider $\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}$ on $[0,1]$ with general conditions $Au(0)+Bu'(0)=0$ and $Cu(1)+Du'(1)=0$ where not both $A$,$B$ are $0$ and not both $C$, $D$ are $0$, you can get up to TWO positive eigenvalues for this operator! I know it sounds crazy, but it's true. The conditions can be even stranger for a 2D case of Laplacian, but at least as strange as this one because of separation of variables.

Comment: @NickThompson : A simple case where $\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}$ on $[0,1]$ has one positive eigenvalue is where you choose conditions $u(0)+u'(0)=0$ and $u(1)+u'(1)=0$. You can check that $e^{-x}$ is an eigenfunction with eigenvalue $1$ for this particular problem. The conditions $u'(0)=-u(0)$ and $u'(1)=-u(1)$ are admittedly unusual, but not entirely crazy either. These are unstable states for the Heat equation, of course, which tells you what's going on in terms of energy.

Comment: That's a very nice thing to know; by the way, where did you learn these statements of PDE solutions in terms of functional calculus? Terry Tao just posted one http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/11/05/discretised-wave-equations/ (namely, a wave equation solution via $u(x,t) = \cos(t\sqrt(-\Delta))u(x,0)$ for $\partial_t u(x,0) = 0$, and of course $\left| \psi(t) \right> = \exp(it\mathcal{H})\left|\psi(0)\right>$, but is there a way to generate these expressions systematically?

Comment: @NickThompson : Really it's just Fourier's method of separation of variables abstracted to separate the time and the space. You have to keep in mind that Fourier's heat problems are historically viewed as the force behind the development of Spectral Theory and much of modern rigor in general (see J. Dieudonne *A History of Functional Analysis*) . The abstraction to exponential time evolution came from Heaviside and his calculus, eventually culminating in $C^{0}$ semigroup theory where $e^{t\Delta}$ becomes fully general, rigorous and elegant.